# React Native - How to rename camera roll image file name

Tags: react-native

I'm having a problem using `@react-native-community/cameraroll`.

Here's my code:

```
const handleSaveImageToDevice = async () => {
    try {
      const uri = await captureRef(viewRef, {
        format: 'jpg',
        quality: 0.8,
      });

      const image = CameraRoll.save(uri, {
        type: 'photo',
        album: 'Generated Image',
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  };
```

As seen in the code I used `captureRef` to save react elements with `ref` as image.

The behavior is working as expected. If the user clicks the save button the image will be saved to the designated folder. But the problem is it saves random file name. I want to rename it like for example "generated_image".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this but I already found a way to fix my problem using third party library `react-native-fs`

```
viewShot?.current?.capture().then((data) => {
        RNFS.writeFile(
          RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath +
            `/generated-image.jpg`,
          data,
          'base64',
        ).then((success) => {
          return CameraRoll.save(
            RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath +
              `/generated-image.jpg`,
            {
              type: 'photo',
              album: 'testing',
            },
          );
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are capturing there is option for image file name:

```
const uri = await captureRef(viewRef, {
        format: 'jpg',
        quality: 0.8,
        fileName: 'generated_image'
      });
```

Refer below link:
https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot/issues/116#issuecomment-1155523609

Comment: I tried it, however it only works on android devices. Is there any other way that supports both android and iOS platforms.

Comment: yes you are right, react native view shot only support android.

Comment: you have to another libraray for rename image file.